# LINQ to SQL Any() throws ArgumentException when called on array of db fields

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, search

I tried to refactor the following code (which filters some database records by category and search term):

```
from entry in _DB.TheTable
join otherEntry in _DB.AnotherTable
on entry.PrimaryKey equals otherEntry.Field
where category.Any(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) 
   || category.Contains(entry.ProductGroup)
where String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm)
   || entry.ProductNumber.Contains(searchTerm)
   || otherEntry.Name1.Contains(searchTerm)
   || otherEntry.Name2.Contains(searchTerm)
   || otherEntry.Name3.Contains(searchTerm)
select new {entry.Something, entry.SomethingElse};
```

to look like this:

```
from entry in _DB.TheTable
join otherEntry in _DB.AnotherTable on entry.PrimaryKey equals otherEntry.Field
let searchFields = new[]{entry.ProductNumber, otherEntry.Name1, otherEntry.Name2,/*...*/}
where category.Any(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) 
   || category.Contains(entry.ProductGroup)
where String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm) 
   || searchFields.Any(field=>field.Contains(searchTerm))
select new {entry.Something, entry.SomethingElse};
```

Unfortunately, LINQ to SQL doesn't seem to be capable of doing this: I get an `ArgumentException` from the code `searchFields.Any(field=>field.Contains(searchTerm))` stating that

> The argument `value` was of the wrong type. Expected: `System.String.` Actual: `System.String[].`

How can I adjust this to work?

EDIT: sorry, forgot to mention `searchTerm` is a `string`, `category` is a `string[]`.

Comment: What is the type of searchTerm?

Comment: sorry, completely forgot to include that. edited.

Comment: what is "where category.Any(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace)"?

Comment: @AmiramKorach it checks if there's a empty `string` or `null` in the category array.

Comment: @codesparkle `where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` is probably a typo and should read `where String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` as in your first query.

Comment: @BigYellowCactus absolutely, thank you.

Comment: @codesparkle otherwise, I am not able to reproduce your problem. Your code seems to be correct, and I also tried your queries in LinqPad, and they work as expected....

Comment: @BigYellowCactus interesting. are you running that against a SQL server? ...

Comment: @codesparkle No. So maybe it's probably a linq2sql thing? I don't know how linq2sql handles the `let` clause. Could you log the generated SQL?

Comment: the exception gets thrown during SQL generation. Thanks for your help, but I fear LINQ to SQL can't handle the code properly... unless there's a different way I haven't thought of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only workaround I found was to concatenate all the fields to be searched into one string and to check if the search term is contained within. Of course, this may return false positives, and a seperator would have to be inserted in between the fields to prevent that.

```
from entry in _DB.TheTable
join otherEntry in _DB.AnotherTable on entry.PrimaryKey equals otherEntry.Field
let searchFields = entry.ProductNumber + otherEntry.Name1 + otherEntry.Name2 
                   + otherEntry.Name3
where category.Any(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace) 
        || category.Contains(entry.ProductGroup)
where String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(searchTerm)
        || searchFields.Contains(searchTerm)
select new {entry.Something, entry.SomethingElse};
```

I'm still open for better solutions and will accept other answers if they provide one. For the meantime, I've gone back to the original version shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: The solution given here is not correct

*The problem you have is that Contains, can only get String values, and you are passing String[].
I'm thinking that maybe you could do `searchTerm.Contains(field)` to set correctly the condition for the `Any` function, because the `field` variable is a String and you're looking for values that are into `searchTerm`
I hope this can help you.
See you!*

Comment: `field` is a string, and `searchTerm` is also a string. How am I "passing String[]"?

Comment: the second part of your answer doesn't make sense either: I want to check if `field` contains `searchTerm`, not the opposite.

Comment: The second part corresponds to my error, surely thinking that searchTerm was `string[]` and not `string`. In that case I really don't know, maybe you can have the error anywhere else, because the code is correct for me. But it says, you're passing a parameter named `value` as a `String[]` when it demands a `String`